# ReactJS and Meteor: Generating <select> options?

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, input, reactjs

I'm using React and Meteor to generate a table of information about items in a catalog. I also made a form so that users can add new items. Each item has a name, price and manufacturer. This works perfectly fine when I make all the inputs text areas, but I want to make the manufacturer input a  with  tags generated according to a Meteor collection called Manufacturers.

```
Form = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    manufacturer: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  renderOptions(){
    return(<option value={this.props.manufacturer.name}>{this.props.manufacturer.name}</option>);
  },
  submitItem(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name=React.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).value.trim();
    var price=React.findDOMNode(this.refs.priceInput).value.trim();
    var manufacturer=React.findDOMNode(this.refs.manufacturerInput).value.trim();
    Items.insert({
      name: name,
      price: price,
      manufacturer: manufacturer,
    });
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).value="";
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.priceInput).value="";
  },
  render(){
    return(
      <footer>
        <form className="new-item" onSubmit={this.submitItem}>
          <input type="text" ref="nameInput" placeholder="Name" required />
          <input type="text" ref="priceInput" placeholder="Price" required />
          <button onClick={this.submitItem}>ADD</button>
        </form>
        <select ref="manufacturerInput" defaultValue="" required />
          <option value="" disabled>Manufacturer</option>
          {this.renderOptions()}
        </select>
      </footer>
    );
  }
});
```

How do I make this work? I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to figure it out, but Meteor just keeps telling me "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for  (38:8)". What am I doing wrong here? It works just fine when they're all  but this destroys my entire app.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally closed your `select` element here:

```
<select ref="manufacturerInput" defaultValue="" required />
```

Remove the `/`.

Comment: Thanks! My app builds successfully, but now I have a different problem: React is telling me "Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `manufacturer` was not specified in `Form`. Check the render method of `App`. form.jsx:6" in the console. But this props code is the same I've used in other components that needed access to data, such as the table actually displaying the items. What gives?

Comment: `propTypes` are for validation of what's being passed. Are you passing a`manufacturer` prop when rendering this component? `<Form manufacturer={someObj}/>`

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I fixed that and now it's rendering the form five times (one for each manufacturer) with the default option and the generated option each time, haha! I'm gonna work on that now...

Comment: I commented out proptypes and remade the renderOptions function:

  renderOptions(){
    return this.data.manufacturer.map((manufacturer) => {
      return <option manufacturer={manufacturer} />;
    });
  },

which refers to this:

option = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    manufacturer: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  render(){
    return(
      <option value={this.props.manufacturer.name}>{this.props.manufacturer.name}</option>
    );
  }
});

But I still get "cannot read property 'manufacturer' of undefined."